# InvalidDataContractException is an invalid collection type since it have DataContractAttribute

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, serialization, datacontract

I have this code:

```
[DataContract]
class MyData
{
    private Int32 dato1;
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Dato1
    {
        get { return dato1; }
        set { dato1 = value; }
    }

    public MyData(Int32 dato1)
    {
        this.dato1 = dato1;
    }
    public MyData()
    {
        this.dato1 = 0;
    }
}

[DataContract]
class MyCollection2 : List<MyData>
{
    public MyCollection2()
    {
    }

}
```

Then I try to serialize one object of MyCollection2 with:

```
MyCollection2 collec2 = new MyCollection2();
collec2.Add(new MyData(10));
DataContractSerializer ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyCollection2));
using (Stream s = File.Create(dialog.FileName))
{
    ds.WriteObject(s, collec2);
}
```

Then I get the next exception:

> InvalidDataContractException is an invalid collection type since it
>   have DataContractAttribute

However, if I use the next class (doesn't inherit directly from List, instead has a List member):

```
[DataContract]
class MyCollection1
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<MyData> items;

    public MyCollection1()
    {
        items = new List<MyData>();
    }

}
```

Here Serialization works ok. Do you know why ?.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `[CollectionDataContract(...)]` instead of `[DataContract]`. For more details see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute.aspx).

For full details see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Just adding `[CollectionDataContract]` solved it for me, thanks!